# How to define composite primary key for a table which already has a primary key using alter command?

Tags: oracle11g, primary-key, alter-table, composite-primary-key

I need to know how to define a composite primary key using `ALTER` table command when a primary key is already defined for the existing table?

**Database:** Oracle 11g

Comment: Even though you tend to use this from a Java EE application I cannot see the relevance of the `[java]` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Drop the existing `PRIMARY KEY` constraint and then re-create it. Assuming the existing one is called `table_pk`, and that the new composite primary key will be on `column1` and `column2`:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP CONSTRAINT table_pk;
ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT table_pk PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2);
```

Comment: Add constraint %constraintName% not works in Oracle [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html#rrefsqlj13590)